# Aggregate Data in R, don't know how

Tags: r

Could someone please help me?
I have a dataset that looks like this:

| Month | Year | Gender | Region |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2017 | male | NY |
| 1 | 2017 | male | NY |
| 1 | 2017 | male | CA |
| 2 | 2017 | male | NY |
| 1 | 2018 | male | NY |
| 1 | 2018 | male | NJ |
| 1 | 2019 | male | NY |
| 2 | 2019 | male | NY |

I want to create a code with the following output:

| Month | Year | Gender | Region | Counts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2017 | male | NY | 4 |
| 2 | 2017 | male | NY | 2 |
| 1 | 2018 | male | NY | 5 |
| 1 | 2019 | male | NY | 4 |
| 2 | 2019 | male | NY | 3 |

A code that count the incidents in month and year.

Comment: What do you call as incident.  Perhaps `df1 %>% add_count(Month, Year)`?

Comment: `add_count` will keep all the rows and add a count for how many times each variable combination appears. `count` will summarize the data more like the desired output.

Comment: I have a dataset but want to aggregate it so that every month and year, when someone died came only one, but add a column with number, so that it is visible how many died on january 2017 in state of ny for example and

Comment: @AnyAnymi Can you tell us how you are getting those values in expected from the input data showed.  The logic is not clear.  If you can update your post with how you derived the values, it is great.  Otherwise, this question may get closed for lack of clarity. thanks

Comment: @AnyAnymi From the input data, I can't find any info about `when someone died`

Comment: Month 1 is for January and year 2017 and there are many rows with these month and year and I want that it comes only once but add a column that shows how many

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by_all() %>% 
  count()
#> # A tibble: 7 x 5
#> # Groups:   Month, Year, Gender, Region [7]
#>   Month  Year Gender Region     n
#>   <int> <int> <chr>  <chr>  <int>
#> 1     1  2017 male   CA         1
#> 2     1  2017 male   NY         2
#> 3     1  2018 male   NJ         1
#> 4     1  2018 male   NY         1
#> 5     1  2019 male   NY         1
#> 6     2  2017 male   NY         1
#> 7     2  2019 male   NY         1
```

---

**Data**

```r
df <- structure(list(Month = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), Year = c(2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2018L, 2018L, 2019L, 2019L), Gender = c("male", 
"male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male", "male"), Region = c("NY", 
"NY", "CA", "NY", "NY", "NJ", "NY", "NY")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))

df
#>   Month Year Gender Region
#> 1     1 2017   male     NY
#> 2     1 2017   male     NY
#> 3     1 2017   male     CA
#> 4     2 2017   male     NY
#> 5     1 2018   male     NY
#> 6     1 2018   male     NJ
#> 7     1 2019   male     NY
#> 8     2 2019   male     NY
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Looks good. But the code doesn't work for me. I want to filter the dataset. I want to aggregate every month and year in which male person died in the state of new york on january 2017, but add a column that counts the number of male person in ny who died

Comment: @AnyAnymi that's what this does - look at the top data frame in my answer. In your example data frame, there were two males who died in NY in month 1 in 2017, so the column n has a value of 2. The **Data** section at the bottom is just a reproducible example of the data in your question. It is the top part that is the answer.